# T-SQL > Self Join > where clause not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, self-join

This will be my very first post, hopefully I'm posting this question with enough detail & making it specific enough.

Firstly, I'm joining a table to itself (Structure s1 JOIN Structure s2).

This table is then joined to another table (planning_entity pe).

I've then applied two filters to the results of the above:

```
pe.short_name = '1024824'
s2.structure_code = s1.father_code
```

**The intention is to return only those rows where s2.structure_code and s1.father_code**. However, the results from my query below seem to return ALL values for s2.structure_code and s1.father_code.
Is my self join not structured correctly? Or have I not stipulated the filters correctly?

As you can probably tell, I'm very new to SQL...any help at all is very much appreciated...

```
SELECT pe.short_name, s2.description, s1.father_code, s2.structure_code
FROM structure s1
INNER JOIN structure s2 ON s1.father_code = s2.structure_code
INNER JOIN planning_entity pe ON s2.structure_code = pe.planning_code
WHERE pe.short_name ='1024824'
AND s2.structure_code = s1.father_code
ORDER BY s2.structure_code
```

Self Join - results

[image]

Comment: Your result seem ok. What output did you expected instead of this? Remove duplicate?

Comment: Sorry - to add a little clarity - What I need ultimately is to return the Description (i.e. in this case 'DRE28 FY19 etc..') for a Short_Name where Father_Code and Structure_Code are the same...does that make sense?

Comment: The part `AND s2.structure_code = s1.father_code` is redundant in the `WHERE` clause since it already appears in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Not clear, in the result you show, you just got the description. Then what is your problem? If duplication is your problem then plz show result of these 3 queries: `SELECT * FROM structure WHERE father_code = '106729';`
`SELECT * FROM structure WHERE structure_code = '106729';`
`SELECT * FROM planning_entity WHERE planning_code = '106729' AND short_name ='1024824';`

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results.

Comment: But you are returning description and `Father_Code = Structure_Code`

Comment: Yeh...'description' is being returned for all father_codes/structure_codes...I'm basically trying to return 'description' ONLY for those lines where father_code = structure_code...

Comment: All rows of your output seem to show the same values for `father_code` and `structure-code`... Assumably your `planning_entity` brings back more rows per `s` then you expect. Did you try `SELECT DISTINCT ...`?

Comment: Unfortunately the interface I'm using doesn't allow copying of results to the clipboard...hence the screen shot...sorry about that

Comment: Sorry - it looks as though I've left out some of the SQL needed to include the correct result set...will post back shortly with the complete query and results!

Comment: Just run these 3 queries: `these 3 queries: SELECT * FROM structure WHERE father_code = '106729';` `SELECT * FROM structure WHERE structure_code = '106729';` `SELECT * FROM planning_entity WHERE planning_code = '106729' AND short_name ='1024824';`

Comment: For every line `Father_Code = Structure_Code`  VTC

Comment: Why using self join? Your comments are bit ambiguous - do you have some kind of tree structure there (linked by father_code) or you need to find records from structure table, where father_code equals structure_code?

Comment: Hi. You are not explaining what rows you want in the result. Your query is equivalent to taking all possible combinations of rows made from s1, s2 & pe & keeping those where the on & where conditions are true. What rows *do* you want? Also "*where s2.structure_code and s1.father_code* & "for s2.structure_code and s1.father_code" do not make sense, what did you mean? We can't say whether you "stipulated the filters correctly" until you explain what rows you want. Also please read & act on [mcve]. And free OCR is online. Text please not images. Also clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: PS It is extremely unlikely that you want to join pe without any condition involving s1 or s2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, Your query works well just need to change select columns as below and improved it by removing where clause.
Copy the query and check the output. I hope it will be done as you required that I understand from your mention problem. Must share your experience.

```
SELECT pe.short_name, s1.description, s1.father_code, s2.structure_code
FROM structure s1
INNER JOIN structure s2 ON 
   s1.father_code = s2.structure_code
INNER JOIN planning_entity pe ON 
   s2.structure_code = pe.planning_code and
   pe.short_name ='1024824'
ORDER BY s2.structure_code
```

Comment: Welcome, Merla!